# import MySQL 5.7 MyISAM to MySQL8 InnoDB £ no longer displaying

Tags: php, mysql

I have recently imported a mysql 5.7 database to mysql8 a table which was myisam in mysql 5.7 is now Innodb in mysql8 any content which contains a £ either doesn't display at all and I mean not just the symbol itself the entire row doesn't show or it is appended with a funny A symbol.

is there a way to fix this?

Comment: 1. What's the data look like in the database now? Is it stored as "£" in the database, or is it already gobbledygook there? 2. Depending on the answer to one, either 2.1: you messed up the import, or 2.2: you fail to establish the right connection encoding and/or further treatment of the data in your code.

Comment: @deceze its showing in the database as "£"

Comment: Then the problem appears to be on your PHP side and you'll need to follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/279279/476.